# In CoffeeScript how do you append a value to an Array?

Tags: arrays, append, coffeescript

What is the prescribed way to append a value to an Array in CoffeeScript?  I've checked the PragProg CoffeeScript book but it only discusses creating, slicing and splicing, and iterating, but not appending.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Good old `push` still works.

```
x = []
x.push 'a'
```

Comment: Author of the [PragProg book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) here. +1 to Thilo's answer. I didn't want to cover the `Array` prototype methods in the book, since there's plenty of good JavaScript documentation out there already. See, for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2

Comment: What about if we have an object, and not a character?

Comment: I was expecting [`x << 'a'`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) to work.

Answer (score 50):

Far better is to use list comprehensions.

For instance rather than this:

```
things = []
for x in list
  things.push x.color
```

do this instead:

```
things = (x.color for x in list)
```

Comment: That doesn't append values from list to things. That replaces the things array entirely. I just tested it too.

Comment: Well, sure ajsie, you're correct, it does replace it, not append. The point is, however, that usually when you are pushing, you are often doing something **quite like** an array comprehension anyway. Not in all cases, admittedly, but a lot of the time.

Comment: @suranyami On the contrary, I can't think of any good use for that. I'd much rather just do `things = list`, it's far more succinct.

Comment: @suranyami The link is dead.

Comment: @anthropomorphic Well, of course. It's a contrived example. Let's say it's something like this instead:

`colors = (item.color for item in list)`

Comment: Oh, I see your intention now.

Comment: Replaced link: [CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/) describes some other options for concatenating and merging arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If you are chaining calls then you want the append to return the array rather than it's length.
In this case you can use .concat([newElement])

Has to be [newElement] as concat is expecting an array like the one its concatenating to.
Not efficient but looks cool in the right setting.

Comment: Chaining calls is more of a stylish thing you can do however, as you stated "the method not being efficient" - `concat` returns a new array constructed from the elements of array A + array B. References to objects are kept so changes to an object referenced in either array A, array B or the concat result will be reflected in the other arrays as well.